# Can we say "rather than to + Verb", Eg: rather than to live abroad?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

[Here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-degree/rather) they say

> We use **rather than** to give more importance to one thing when two
>   alternatives or preferences are being compared:
>
> He wanted to be an actor rather than a comedian.
>
> Can we come over on Saturday rather than Friday?
>
> **Rather than** usually occurs between two things which are being compared. However, we can also use it at the beginning of a sentence.
>   **When we use rather than with a verb, we use the base form or (less commonly) the -ing form of a verb**:
>
> Rather than pay the taxi fare, he walked home. (or Rather than paying
>   the taxi fare, he walked home.)
>
> **Not**: Rather than to pay …

But [this site](http://www.grammarbank.com/would-rather-would-prefer.html) has 2 examples:

*I would prefer ('d prefer) my son to live with me rather than to live abroad.*

*I would prefer your daughter to have accepted my apology rather than to have ignored me last night.*

I would think the site is wrong.

We have to say

*I would prefer ('d prefer) my son to live with me rather than live abroad.*

*I would prefer your daughter to have accepted my apology rather than have ignored me last night.*

Can we say "**rather than to + Verb**"?

Answer (score -1):

It is important that the two alternatives have the same grammatical form so, for example:

> *I would prefer my son to live with me rather than live abroad.*

is wrong because "to live with me" is infinitive while "live abroad" is simple present.  You could use either:

> *I would prefer my son to live with me rather than abroad.*

where the alternatives "with me" and "abroad" agree or:

> *I would prefer my son to live with me rather than to live abroad.*

where the alternative "to live with me" and "to live abroad" agree.

Where the alternatives involve different verbs, for example:

> I would prefer your daughter **to have** accepted my apology rather than **to have** ignored me last night.

the verbs must agree.

Comment: "My mother would prefer us to email each other once a week, rather than spend half an hour on the phone every night." They don't say to spend" http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv107.shtml